# Empty array after get request (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ajax, angular-resource

In my example when I send a GET request to get a response array with data, then I see in the console of firefox the array is empty. I don't know where the error is.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
//Controller:
$scope.changeDate = function (selFrom) {
     vm.repos = CrudService.getRepoByDay(selFrom);
}


//Service (CrudService):
function CrudService(ResService) {
    var service = {
        getRepoByDay: getRepoByDay
    };

    return service;

    function getRepoByDay(selTo) {
      return ResourceService.test.query(
         { endDate: selTo },
         successResponse,
         errorResponse
      );
    }

    function successResponse(response) {
       return response;
    }
}

//Service (ResService)
test: $resource(baseUrl + '/api/repodates', {
         endDate: '@EndDate'
}, {})

//View
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="report in rc.repos>
    <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in report">
        {{ value }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Do anyone have an idea what I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$resource is asynchronous you have to handle it in the callback of the promise :

```
return ResourceService.test.query(
     { endDate: selTo } 
);

CrudService.getRepoByDay(selFrom).$promise.then(function(data){
       vm.repos = data;
       console.log(data);//log here not ouside the callback to check
});
```

EDIT sample with $q :

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
ResourceService.test.query(
    { endDate: selTo } 
).$promise.then(
     function(data){deferred.resolve(data);},
     function(rejection){deferred.reject(rejection);}
);
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: that means, in the service of CrudService I mustn't define `successResponse`?

Comment: yes since $promise is a promise you don't need to define a raw callback

Comment: Do you have an example with `$q`, `.resolve` and `.reject`?

Comment: i edited my post, but you don't need thatwith angular-resource

Comment: Why I don't need this for `$resource`? Is there an article to read when I have to define `$q`?

Comment: $resource.$promise is a promise, then why would you need to use another promise created by $q ?

Comment: Perhaps it could be, that the approach with `$q` is a better practice? I don't know therefore I'm asking.

Comment: No, that would be only a useless redondancy in that specific case. Now if you cahce somewhat your data, you may need $q in order to mock the result from fetcing from the cache instead of doing a request.